# jQuery selecting the 3rd, 4th and 5th TD in every row with ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having some difficulties selecting the proper cells in a table.
I have a soccer games tables. Each table starts with ID 'game' and then the serial number, i.e: `id='game122238'`.

Each table has two rows. On the first row, I have 5 cells.
On the second one, I have one team.
On the third one, I have the result.
On the Fourth, I have the second team.

**I succeeded selecting all tables**:

```
$('table[id^=game]');
```

But then I got stuck. How could I:
A. getting all 'home teams' into one array.
B. getting all results in another array.
C. getting all 'away teams' into third array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use children() to iterate through the tr's and td's to get the values you want. Ort another way would be:

```
var i = 0;
$('table[id^=game] tr td').each(function() {
 switch(i) {
  case 0: { alert("First TD:" + $(this).html()); break; }
  case 1: { alert("Second TD:" + $(this).html()); break; }
  // ...
 }
 i++;
});
```

Would be easier, if you've got osme example tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped me to have the break through. Well I understood that in this aweful table all td's a getting 1st, 2d, 3rd and so on, and it could end up in few hundreds, so I couldn't use the exact switch case.
but I have used something similar, that count the number of cells in a row and then by the relative offset determine if to get the HTML value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the [nth Child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('table[id^=game] tr td:nth-child(3)'); // would select all cells that were in the 3rd column
```

If you are able to provide a sample of your HTMl I might be able to give a more concrete example.

Comment: i noticed nth-Child has to be lowercase for it to work. --> nth-child(3)